# Using post commit hook in visualsvn server to trigger a build in teamcity while obeying quiet period

Tags: batch-file, teamcity, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

How do I setup VisualSVN Server to trigger Teamcity to build a specific project after someone commits to it while obeying the set quiet period?

Right now I am using this in the post commit hook of visual svn server:

```
wget http://<user name>:<user password>@<server address>/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=<build type Id>
```

The problem with this is I need the build type ID to change depending on what project was committed to and the other problem is that it starts the build right away and ignores my set quiet period of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Use the VCSupdate plugin for teamcity and use wget on thevcsupdate url for the vcs root.